# How to use system() with std::thread together in C++

Tags: c++, string, multithreading, std, external

I am writing a `C++` program on a win10 platform. I need to launch an external exe file in the second thread. The path of this external file is stored in a `std::string` object.

This external program will run for a very long time and it will output a result file every minute. And my main thread will go and read this file every minute. **So I don't want the second thread to block my main thread.**

I first write the following code, it can work:

```
string exePath = "external_program.exe";
const char* exePathChar = exePath.c_str();
system(exePathChar);
```

Then I update the code and try  `std::thread` to enable a new thread to run the external exe file. But `system()` cannot open the specified file.

```
string exePath = "external_program.exe";
const char* exePathChar = exePath.c_str();
thread t1(system, exePathChar);
t1.detach();
```

I try to define the path as char* type at the beginning and the code works:

```
const char* exePathChar = "external_program.exe";
system(exePathChar);
```

The problem is that this file path is not fixed, it needs to read the external `json` file to get it, and the load function can only return `string` type. So how can I pass this `string` type path parameter to the `thread t1(system)`? Or is there any better solution?

Comment: Just run the thread with a lambda which captures the string by value. There's no reason at all an arbitrary C library function should act perfectly as a thread entry point and it's sort of weird even to try. Specifically, it's your responsibility to guarantee that `exePath` still exists when it's used in the other thread.

Comment: Don't use `system()` *ever*. 1) It's a security *nightmare*. 2) It's difficult to interact with the spawned process. 3) It's difficult to get standard output and error streams from the spawned process. 4) It's a hassle when porting code between operating systems. 5) You have no control over what command interpreter will be used. 6) You have little control over the environment of the spawned process. -  And much much more.  Just forget it exists - there are better ways to spawn a process.

Comment: PS. You can easily verify this is the problem by just changing `detach()` to `join()`

Comment: Albeit the criticism: Tried on my system opening `notepad.exe`, actually worked like a charm... Still joining in, don't use `system` (and additionally: you create yet another process in between, the shell itself, which then creates the final process – another reason why to avoid). Unfortunately there's no standard library for child process management, so you'll rely on OS-specific means (-> `CreateProcess` on windows).

Comment: NB. The advice about not using `system` in the first place is absolutely correct. You just _also_ have an obvious threading error.

Comment: Advantage of `CreateProcess` (or `fork` + `exec[...]` on posix): It returns upon process creation, you don't need yet another thread to monitor... Once you are done with your own work you can simply call `WaitForSingleObject` using the appropriate handle to wait until the child process terminates. Then close the handles and you are fine. If need be, there are means to kill the child process as well.

Comment: [`boost::process::system`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/process.html) is really useful for stuff like this.

Comment: @Useless I hope the second thread doesn't block the main thread. I.e. this external program runs in the background and my main process reads its output file every 1 minute from the hard disk. If I understand correctly, using `join()` will block my main thread right?

Comment: @Aconcagua I checked `CreateProcess` just now, seems it will block my main thread. I hope the second thread doesn't block the main thread. I.e. this external program is running in the background and the next function of my main process will read its output file in the hard disk every 1 minute and then do some further calculations. In short, I don't want to wait for this external program to finish executing.

Comment: @peterliu using join will block your main thread _but allow you to verify that the string lifetime is a problem_. I didn't suggest leaving it like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `ShellExecute()` instead of `system()`:

```cpp
void RunExe(const std::wstring& exe)
{
    ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", exe.c_str(), NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
}

int main(void)
{
    std::jthread(RunExe, L"notepad.exe").join();

    std::string test = "Test text";

    std::cout << test << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It's located in `windows.h`

Comment: Thanks, it works. I still use the system(), but follow your idea, first convert the string to char* in a new function (RunExe()) and send it to the system() inside this function. Then send this RunExe() to 2nd thread.